# Designing a matrix webpage

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking forward to designing a web page with a matrix layout. like #. It would have max. 8 columns and 3 rows.

I have decided on 8 columns as every screen width resolution on PC, mobile, tablets divides perfectly by 8. I have decided on 3 rows as it is readable. Though vertical scroll bar shows automatically, asking a visitor to click it to see the content is a pain to him. So, visitor needs to see complete paragraphs/sections the first he sees the page.

When I left coding for web (as I started managing my team members. I hardly used to program until some time back and seem to lost out a lot.) when CSS/js was just coming out. Now it dominates even the HTML. So, using CSS is the way to go. (Imho, I actually find coding CSS a scary job).

Looks to be a huge requirement, after I have searched for the resources online.

Problems:
* Fixed columns over different resolutions
* Fixed rows
* Placing right content in right matrix boxes.

How do I start?

Update: I am a huge fan of http://www.nytimes.com/chrome. The main screen which shows assorted news in a matrix is a wonderful and unique design. The matrix changes dynamically to respond to changing screen resolution.

How can we design it?

Comment: That, sir, is called a grid layout. I was thinking of a black webpage with articles scrolling vertically in strips.

Comment: hm, do what I do, find a nice template that fits the above specifications, use that ;)

Comment: @Dhaivat, whoa there. I'd go easy on the OP. What he speaks of exists in some form, as it's just a grid layout.

Comment: There's just too many of these people here, Blender. I bet he hasn't even glanced at the FAQ, or spent two seconds going over his post again. If we don't force these people to change SO is going to change into the web developer forums that we all hate.

Comment: @Dhaivat: Telling people to GTFO the first time they post? Great way to have people participate. I have never read the FAQ, nor do I plan on doing it. You can learn by deduction that this isn't a webforum, but seriously, chill. I doubt you browsed here, whipped out the FAQ, and studied it like a boss.

Comment: @Nitin - as far as all screen width resolutions being divisible by 8, I don't see how that helps you. You care about available width *in the browser*, which may have a vertical scrollbar taking up space, may not be maximised, etc.

Comment: Blender: well, I guess I was a bit too harsh, but this is the 11th question today that had absolutely no code, and was terribly phrased.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, first, you forget about non-standard grid of 8x3. Then, you

- [Check the demo](http://960.gs/demo.html);
- [Download 960 grid system](http://960.gs/);
- [Read tutorial with the video](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/a-detailed-look-at-the-960-css-framework/);

start using that grid. Will be much easier to maintain it in the future

Comment: I would go with www.getskeleton.com

Answer (score 0):

You may care about [this](http://960.gs/).
If not, just make `<ul>` and `<table>` forms.

Comment: I have studied 960.gs carefully and it is not something I would go with. The layout should not be fixed for every resolution. It should float to match every resolution. I didn't say grid only because it does not offer a flexible layout to match a given resolution.
Problem with the floating layout is that the columns stretch to the width of the monitor. Apart from gmail, I have hardly seen it effective.

Comment: Do it yourself with <ul> and <table> forms with Javascript to make a declarative interface. I warn you, its a lot of work.